# Advice needed on exam application design

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I am creating a desktop software in WPF that is more like an exam...So I have four sections of the exam, the exam to be taken is selected by the user on the basis of a number selected from a dropdownList control. So once a user selects a number from a drop down, it goes to the database and retrieves the questions with that ID and displays in a grid view control. Now my question is:
1)Should I store the title of the Exam in the database,so when the user selects a value from drop down,the heading is retrieved from the table corresponding to that dropdown value and then when subsequently when user clicks the start button,it starts displaying the questions in the database.First section on the first page,second section on the second page and so on..

Anyone got a better idea? Please suggest, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Please try to make the title of your post more specific and descriptive. "Help me!!!" style titles may turn down many people, who otherwise might be competent to answer your question.

Comment: It's tagged as homework.

Comment: @kzh, @Justin McLachlan: please read carefully, OP asked about design for application managing exam entries, not about creating that application during an exam or something of the sort.

Comment: It doesn't matter what he asked about. It's TAGGED as homework already. Sounds like homework.

Comment: Well, first of all,thanks for editing the post and make it more presentable. FYI this is not a homework problem, its a problem related to something I have to do at work, so I am really desperate to find the help.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest 2 tables (simplified):

**EXAM**: columns `ID`, `TITLE`

**EXAM_QUESTION**: columns `ID`, `EXAM_ID` (foreigh key to `EXAM.ID`), `QUESTION`

When you start your application, you load the entire **EXAM** table and bind your dropdown list to it. Each time user selects an item in that dropdown list, you load the list of corresponding **EXAM_QUESTION** entries and bind your grid (that would be ideally cached).

Comment: Definately a good start to the problem. There may be more to the 'Question' field depending on what's required. You'd probably want a method to specify the order of the questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with three tables (assuming it'll offer multiple choice). Exams, exam_questions, and question_answers. An exam can have many questions, an exam_question can have many question_answers.

```
exams: ID, TITLE
exam_questions: ID, EXAM_ID, QUESTION
question_answers: ID, EXAM_QUESTIONS_ID, ANSWER
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help but my question really is If the method I suggested is an acceptable way to execute it or there could be some better way?